# Google streets view api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Hi i am trying to show a png like image of a location's street view , using the street view api. I created a div of 80 by 80 pixels and fr panorama options i passed in the following...

```
position: loc,
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      enableCloseButton: false,
      panControl: false,
      linksControl: false,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
      addressControl: false,
      pov: {
        heading: 0,
        zoom: 0,
        pitch: 0
      }
```

Now what is happening is due to the small size the default that it renders is a gray map, I have to hold my mouse and drag to see something that looks like a street view.

This does not happening when the map is big in size. Is there anyway to get around the small size issue

Thanks 
-D

Comment: People might find it easier to have a go at solving your problem if you posted some sample code for them to tweak

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this article which shows you an undocumented way to pull thumbnails out of the system?

- http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/15/google-streetview-static-api/

How small are you talking?

Comment: hey I saw that article, unfortunately, can't use that, I am thinking 80px by 80px..

Comment: That article would work for you, you just pass the height and width in that you want. This works to generate an 80x80 thumb: http://cbk0.google.com/cbk?output=thumbnail&w=80&h=80&ll=51.494966,-0.146674